# C++ STD Unordered Set/Map vs Boost Unordered Set/Map

Tags: c++, boost, hash, stl, set

What are the differences between them, and when should you use each?

I have tried a few tests on an old laptop and there seems to be no significant performance difference for storing basic types like ints and longs. I think one of the main difference is boost container emplace methods dont support std::piecewise_construct and tuples, which causes additional overhead.

Edit: the stuff I'm working on already has a lot of boost features, so I'm not worried about compatibility issues with boost libraries.

Comment: The c++ ones are basically taken from boost, and they're newer, so the C++ ones are generally better. However the others work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Boost ones have some features that do not exist in the standard library. Off the top of my head:

- Boost Hash, which is more flexible and easier to customize than specializing `std::hash<>` (though specializing `boost::hash<>` is also supported; the easier route is to implement a `inline friend size_t hash_value(T const&)` which will "magically" be picked up by the default `hash<>` implementation
- Boost tends to support heterogeneous lookup better (look for extended find/insert signatures)
- The ordered versions may have extra constructors to efficiently construct over known ordered sequences
- In general Boost containers (including others from the Boost Container library) have more guarantees/options:

  - (better) support for stateful allocators (including scoped_allocator_adaptor, so with full `uses_allocator`/`allocator_arg_t` support)
  - constructors don't allocate
  - some support for incomplete types in the the template arguments
- As far as I know piecewise construction is perfectly fine in Boost. E.g. Change notes lists for 1.48.0:

  > ```
  > * `emplace` used to emulate the variadic pair constructors that
  >   appeared in early C++0x drafts. Since they were removed it no
  >   longer does so. It does emulate the new `piecewise_construct`
  >   pair constructors - only you need to use
  >   `boost::piecewise_construct`. To use the old emulation of
  >   the variadic constructors define
  > ```

### Summary

I don't expect significant differences in performance.

Quality of implementation differences will exist. Boost's will probably be a bit slower to compile and support older compiler versions.

### BONUS

In reply to the comments, here's a sample outlining some of the features mentioned above and in particular the use of piecewise emplacement:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sdcqa5TYb)**

```
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

struct MyKey {
    MyKey(int i, std::string s) : _i(i), _s(std::move(s)) {}

    bool operator==(MyKey const&) const = default;

  private:
    int _i;
    std::string _s;

    friend size_t hash_value(MyKey const& mk) {
        using boost::hash_value;
        size_t seed = hash_value(mk._i);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, hash_value(mk._s));
        return seed;
    }

    friend auto& operator<<(auto& os, MyKey const& mk) {
        return os << "[" << mk._i << ", " << std::quoted(mk._s) << "]";
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::unordered_map<MyKey, std::string> m;

    m.emplace(boost::unordered::piecewise_construct,
              boost::make_tuple(42, "forty-two"),
              boost::make_tuple("the answer"));

    m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::/*make_*/tuple(43, "forty-three"),
              std::/*make_*/tuple("not the answer"));

    fmt::print("m: {}\n", m);
}
```

Prints

```
m: {([43, "forty-three"], "not the answer"), ([42, "forty-two"], "the answer")}
```

Comment: I never saw boost::piecewise_construct. What is the syntax for emplacing using piecewise_construct and tuples for boost?

Comment: I can give it a try just to see...

Comment: Added a sample to the answer and **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sdcqa5TYb)**

Comment: Ty so much for the syntax. When I was trying out different stuff with std::piecewise_construct and std tuples i got massive unreadable compiler errors. I was trying stuff like m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(...)) and m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(...))

Comment: Those would both work for sets, but in reality, there would not be a need for piecewise (because there are no "pieces"): https://godbolt.org/z/9E8ncor4s